# UIViewControllerRepresentable is crashing on Xcode 14 iOS 16

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to create Xcode previews for my view controller in Xcode 14 beta and iOS 16. When ever I run the code, it just throws some Xcode preview error in the dialog and crashes the preview. I am not using Storyboards, so I am just loading my ViewController2 programmatically.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

final class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
}

struct ViewController2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewController2()
    }
}

extension ViewController2: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController2 {
        ViewController2()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController2, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it only Preview or Simulator crashes as well?

Comment: Only the preview. I ran on simulator and it works fine. I wanted to live preview my ViewController.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ouch... you use class for representable - that's bad idea (even for final!) - use only(!) structs

Here is fixed variant (tested with Xcode 14b2)

```
struct ViewController2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewControllerRep()
    }
}

struct ViewControllerRep: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController2 {
        return ViewController2()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController2, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was stuck on this for a bit! This is indeed a change in iOS 16, it was working fine before.